# How to convert Java code into Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, vector

I have a Java code and I would like to translate into Matlab code. Is there any specific way to do so automatically?

This is the Java code that I have to translate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] v1={1, 1.5, 2, 2.3, 3, 3.4};
    double[] v2={1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 2.4, 3.1, 3.3, 3.5, 3.9, 4, 5.1, 5.6};

    int[] v;
    v = calcolate(v1,v2);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<v.length; i++)
        System.out.println(v[i]);
}

private static int[] calcolate(double[] v1, double[] v2){
    int i, j;
    int[] v = new int[v1.length];
    for(i=0; i<v1.length; i++){
        boolean found = false;
        for(j=0; j<v2.length; j++){
            if(v1[i]<=v2[j] && !found){
                v[i] = j;
                found = true;
            }
        }
    } 
    return v;
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
0
2
3
4
5
7
```

This is the vector `v`. It contains the indices of the vector `v2`, corresponding to the elements of the vector `v2` that are greater than or equal to each element of the vector `v1`.

If I can't do it automatically, are there any functions in Matlab that I can use to compare two vectors with different lengths?

Answer (score 1):

For your algorithm, you can use a Matlab-specific feature called [`arrayfun()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) which executes a function on each value of an array, and returns the results as a new array. The Matlab equivalent of your code above is:

```
v1=[1, 1.5, 2, 2.3, 3, 3.4];
v2=[1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 2.4, 3.1, 3.3, 3.5, 3.9, 4, 5.1, 5.6];
arrayfun(@(x) find(x <= v2, 1), v1)
```

Note that Matlab indices start at 1 (Java indices start at zero), so the output is `1 3 4 5 6 8`

In general you can't *automatically* convert from Java to Matlab because the components of the two languages are not equivalent - for example, Java arrays are not the same as Matlab matrices so they don't always behave the same way. But in many *specific* cases this doesn't matter and you can develop equivalent code. However, a line-by-line conversion isn't always the best thing to do, because each language has its own special features that can help you, such as the `arrayfun()` method I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do in Matlab using a little `for` loop and `find`. In the same structure as your code:

```matlab
function main()
    v1 = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.3, 3, 3.4];
    v2 = [1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 2.4, 3.1, 3.3, 3.5, 3.9, 4, 5.1, 5.6];

    v = calcolate(v1, v2);
    disp(v);
end

function v = calcolate(v1, v2)
    v = zeros(size(v1)); 
    for ii = 1:numel(v1)
        % Find first element (hence the 1) where v2 >= each element of v1
        v(ii) = find(v2 >= v1(ii), 1);
    end
end
```

If you want column vectors instead of row vectors, use semi-colons instead of commas, or use an apostrophe to transpose a vector like `disp(v')`.

Matlab's logical indexing in combination with the `find` function means you don't need the second loop which is in your Java code.

Tom's answer of using `arrayfun` basically lets Matlab do the other looping for you.